# how to convert image to byte and again convert it to image in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, base64

I am trying to use the **image_picker** plugin. I can get the image as file using this plugin. I need to convert this image to bytes and send to a api. So I tried to use dart:convert to convert the  image to byte string. Now when I decode I am getting a **Uint8List** type. How to convert this to a file and display in a **Image.file()**. I couldn’t proceed from here. Can someone help me with this.

consider i am getting this decodedBytes i am getting from a api response, how can i convert them to display in a Image widget

This is the code I tried so far.

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      imageURI = image;
      final bytes = image.readAsBytesSync();

      String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
      print(bytes);
      print(img64);

      final decodedBytes = base64Decode(img64);
      print(decodedBytes);
      //consider i am getting this decodedBytes i am getting from a api response, how can i convert them to display in a Image widget 
    });
```

I am getting this error using **writeAsBytesSync()**,

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'decodedimg.png'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error, because you can't write to any arbitrary location in an application sandbox. You can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to look up a temporary directory.

But in your case, just use the `image` object, `pickImage` already returns a File object, so just use `Image.file(image)`

If you want to decode a base64 into a temporary directory you can use:

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

Future<File> writeImageTemp(String base64Image, String imageName) async {
  final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  await dir.create(recursive: true);
  final tempFile = File(path.join(dir.path, imageName));
  await tempFile.writeAsBytes(base64.decode(base64Image));
  return tempFile;
}
```

with pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
  path: ^1.6.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.7
```

Comment: i will get a base64 string from api i need to convert them to some format and display in a Imgae widget. How to do that? @herbert

Comment: @Anu decode it with base64.decode(), create a file in the temporary directory (if you download it every time new, otherwise in the documents directory), write it.. and you are done.. e.g. ` final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory()`; tempDir.create(recursive: true);final file = File(path.join(tempDir.path, 'tmp.png')); await file.writeBytes(bytes);`

Comment: `getTemporaryDirectory` from https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider -- `path.join` use: `import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;` https://pub.dev/packages/path

Comment: can you please add as code snippent in your answer? @herbert

Comment: @Anu i have added an example how to convert the base64 into a binary image and return a temporary file you could use with `Image.file`.